# Unwanted dll's after publish in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I publish .net core application in Visual Studio 2017 RC, it creates 2 unwanted dll's, which are as follows:

```
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll

Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll
```

It happens only in Visual Studio 2017 RC and not in Visual Studio Express 2015.

I have found following link on github, but fix mentioned over there only removes `ref` folder from publish output.

https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/123

Is there any way, by which I can get rid of these 2 heavy dll's as they size around 2MB in total?

Comment: Have you tried using VS2017 RTM and not RC? It has already shipped and the issue might be fixed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Microsoft.NETCore.App version=1.1.0.  When you reference that version, implicitly (the default), or explicitly, you will get those two assemblies in your publish directory.

The fix is to either upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 RTM, which implicitly references the version with the fix (1.1.1), or to explicitly reference 1.1.1 by adding `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` to your .csproj.